# read file block by block in python

Tags: python, file

I have file that has this format

```
MACRO L20_FDPQ_TV1T8_1
 FIXEDMASK ;
 CLASS CORE ;
 ...
 ...
END L20_FDPQ_TV1T8_1
MACRO INV_20
...
...
END INV_20
```

I want to read the file as blocks such that each MACRO to end of its name form a block in python. I tried to use this

```
with open(file_name, "r") as f_read:
    lines = f_read.readlines()
num = 0
while num < len(lines):
    line = lines[num]
    if re.search(r"MACRO\s+", line, re.IGNORECASE):
            macro_name = line.split()[1]
            while re.search(r"\s+END\s+%s"%macro_name, line, re.IGNORECASE) is None:
                line = lines[num + 1]
                #...do something...
                num = num+1
            num +=1
```

how this can be done in an efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean by _to end of its name_?

Comment: You should show whether you have tried anything or not.

Comment: why are you searching for "MACRO" and "END"? The beginning of a macro must exactly start with "MACRO" and you know it will end when the line starts  exactly with "END". No need to search

Comment: is this is the efficient way? @ahota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumming that you cannot nest Macros, that Macros always start with "MACRO [name]" and end with "END [name]":

```
# read the contents of the file
with open(file_name, "r") as f_read:
    lines = f_read.readlines()

current_macro_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("MACRO"):
        macro_name = line.split()[1]

    # if line starts with END and refers to the current macro name
    elif line.startswith("END") and line.split()[1] == macro_name:
        # here the macro is complete, 
        #put the code you want to execute when you find the end of the macro

        # then when you finish processing the lines, 
        # empty them so you can accumulate the next macro
        current_macro_lines = []

    else:
        # here you can accumulate the macro lines
        current_macro_lines.append(line)
```

Comment: there is "END" line before the "END macro_name" and how can I accumulate macro lines?